# HTTP Version not supported:505

Tags: java, selenium, broken-image

I have written selenium/Java script to find out broken images on a website. Out of 34 images, 2 images are throwing 505 error code(HTTP Version not supported).

Here is my code

```
    HttpURLConnection huc = null;
    int respCode = 200;
    huc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(url).openConnection());
    huc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");

    huc.setConnectTimeout(2000);
    huc.connect();
    respCode = huc.getResponseCode();

    if (respCode >= 400) {
        System.out.println(url + " is a broken with error code:" + respCode);
    } else {
        System.out.println(url + " is a good");
    }
```

```
505 Errors:
https://s7d4.scene7.com/is/image/DuPontCorteva/IMG-Soja-CampoDeSojaConFocoYDesenfoque-0_71-1 Desktop(new)?$callToActionCard_tablet$ is a broken with error code:505

https://s7d4.scene7.com/is/image/DuPontCorteva/IMG-Cenital-VistaCenitalDeCampo-0_71-1 Desktop(new)?$callToActionCard_desktop$ is a broken with error code:505


Few successful responses:
https://s7d4.scene7.com/is/image/DuPontCorteva/IMG-Campo-PersonasCaminandoEnElCampoConAtardecer-0_71-1 Desktop(new)?$callToActionCard_desktop$ is a good
https://s7d4.scene7.com/is/image/DuPontCorteva/IMG-Campo-PersonasCaminandoEnElCampoConAtardecer-0_71-1 Desktop(new)?$callToActionCard_tablet$ is a good
https://s7d4.scene7.com/is/image/DuPontCorteva/IMG-Campo-PersonasCaminandoEnElCampoConAtardecer-0_71-1 Desktop(new)?$callToActionCard_mobile$ is a good
https://s7d4.scene7.com/is/image/DuPontCorteva/IMG-Soja-CampoDeSojaConFocoYDesenfoque-0_71-1 Desktop(new)?$callToActionCard_desktop$ is a good
```

Comment: Interesting. If two give errors, and four work I doubt it's a code issue.

Comment: @ Elliott Frisch - What could be the problem ? Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Issue is with the URL, it contains spaces. You can use Java URL encoder for a generic solution: [Java URL encoding of query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding-of-query-string-parameters)

In your case, just replace your space in %20 as follows:

```
        String url = "https://s7d4.scene7.com/is/image/DuPontCorteva/IMG-Soja-CampoDeSojaConFocoYDesenfoque-0_71-1%20Desktop(new)?$callToActionCard_tablet$";
    HttpURLConnection huc = null;
    int respCode = 200;
    huc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(url).openConnection());
    huc.setRequestMethod("HEAD");

    huc.setConnectTimeout(2000);
    huc.connect();
    respCode = huc.getResponseCode();

    if (respCode >= 400) {
        System.out.println(url + " is a broken with error code:" + respCode);
    } else {
        System.out.println(url + " is a good");
    }
```

output:

```
https://s7d4.scene7.com/is/image/DuPontCorteva/IMG-Soja-CampoDeSojaConFocoYDesenfoque-0_71-1%20Desktop(new)?$callToActionCard_tablet$ is a good
```

Answer (score 1):

Given you use Selenium and Java you should have [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) library "for free" as a part of Selenium's [transitive dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies).

Therefore you can amend your image checking logic to look like:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().build();
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).method("HEAD", null).build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
int respCode = response.code();
```

OkHttp client will automatically take care of the [URL Encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) as your current request fails due to special [characters which are not allowed in URLs](https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/)

You might also want to [obtain browser cookies](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TC/Cookies) and add them to your request as your endpoint might require cookie-based authentication